# XML Doc - null handling

Tags: c#

I have

```
xmlDoc.DataSet.Tables["<tablename>"].Columns
```

I want to loop through those columns via `DataColumn`, for say this `xmlDoc` has 10 entries and 5 are null, then the loop should happen for the non-null entries only.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++ )
{
    DataColumn col = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i] != null ? ds.Tables[0].Columns[i] : "<some default value>";
    if (col != "<some default value>")
                    // do something
}
```

Comment: I keep getting this, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. Any idea?

Comment: I don't really have a place to test this, but have you tried this? --Updated my answer.

Comment: Also, be sure to allow the columns in the dataset in question to allow null values for that column.  You are trying to copy an xml document from a soap service into a strongly typed dataset.  Make sure the dataset has been explicitly set to allow null values for whatever column you believe may have null values.

Comment: Thanks. I was having your similar kind of code in one dataset, but didn't have the same kind of logic for another dataset.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in xmlDoc.DataSet.Tables[""].Columns)
{
    if (column != null)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i do have this kind of code, but i get-> System.Exception: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: Thanks, does it check whether other 5 columns have null value, am getting DBNull cast exception.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 then you would want to use `if (column != DBNull)` instead @Andrew Hare didn't want to hijack a great answer

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new here.  I didn't mean to hijack your answer.  My apologies.  msarchet is correct, and you should also make sure your dataset allow for null values.